# PIL resizing gif loses transparency

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to resize a gif like so:

```py
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image, ImageSequence


def resize_media(
    filename: str,
    width: int,
    height: int
) -> BytesIO:
    im = Image.open(filename)
    ft = im.format

    frames = []
    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
        frame = frame.convert('RGBA')
        frame = frame.resize((width, height))
        b = BytesIO()
        frame.save(b, format=ft, **im.info)
        frames.append(Image.open(b))

    fp = BytesIO()
    frames[0].save(
        fp,
        save_all=True,
        append_images=frames[1:],
        format=ft,
        loop=0,
        disposal=2,
        optimize=True,
        **im.info
    )
    fp.seek(0)
    return fp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = resize_media('in.gif', 256, 256)
    with open('out.gif', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(result.getbuffer())
```

in.gif is:
[image]

The script results in out.gif being:

[image]

As you can see, for some reason the transparency is gone. I've searched online and found that you need to pass transparency=0 to `frames[0].save()` however this totally glitches the gif, instead I am passing im.info which in this case is `{'version': b'GIF89a', 'background': 0, 'transparency': 141, 'duration': 40}`.

EDIT: I am using code from [this](https://gist.github.com/egocarib/ea022799cca8a102d14c54a22c45efe0) gist to save transparent gifs. Not sure why this isn't just supported by PIL.

Comment: GIF transparency is kind of weird, it doesn't surprise me that PIL has trouble with it.

Comment: That `transparency` value is which of the 256 palette colors is intended to be the transparent one.  If you don't use the same palette to encode as was used in the original, it will be total nonsense.

Comment: Yes but frame.info returns an empty dict, so how am I supposed to know what colour is supposed to be transparent per frame? I really don't get it...

Comment: Probably all the frames are using the same palette, and thus the same transparent index.  If I had more time I'd try to work through this for you, it's an interesting problem.